# Finding specified eigenvalue given matrix with variable as a component

Tags: linear-algebra

Given the following question

$$
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & 4 \\
    -4 & k \\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
For $A$ to have an eigenvalue of $0$, what value must $k$ be?

I know that to find eigenvalues you need to use $\det{(A-\lambda I)}$

Using this I get $\lambda^2-k\lambda - \lambda + 16 + k$

Not sure what or how to ascertain a value for $k$ which would ensure $k=0$

Any tips?

Comment: What does the value of the determinant have to be in order to have an eigenvalue to be zero?

Comment: @EuklidAlexandria There is no quadratic equation to be solved here, the matrix is singular

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's even easier. Zero is an eigenvalue if and only if the matrix is not invertible, which happens if and only if its determinant is $0$. Can you find the determinant of your matrix?

Comment: Thanks for the great tip. Got the answer. The trick is to remember that if there is an eigenvalue that is zero the matrix must be singular meaning the actual determinant must be equal to zero also making the question very easy indeed. Thanks again!

Comment: @esc123 You don’t even need to compute the determinant here. The matrix is singular iff its rows/columns are linearly dependent. You should be able to figure out by inspection what $k$ must be in order for the second column to be a multiple of the first.

Answer (score 1):

You want to find a value of $k$ that ensures $\lambda=0$ satisfies $\lambda^2-k\lambda-\lambda+16+k=0$.

If you plug $0$ for $\lambda$ into the characteristic polynomial $\lambda^2-k\lambda-\lambda+16+k$

(which you found correctly), it should be very easy to see what value of $k$ makes the expression $0$.

Comment: This general approach would work even if the given eigenvalue is something other than $0$

Comment: cool thanks for the alternative approach. It may be useful to know that this would work regardless of the eigenvalue given

Comment: You're welcome.  I tried to continue on the path you were taking, though I agree with the others that in the special case of an eigenvalue being $0$ there are shortcuts